# Will ArcGIS for Desktop run on Windows 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation, windows-10, system-requirements

Will ArcGIS 10 run on the new windows 10 technical preview?

I am setting up an interface on my Mac and there is the free option of downloading the Windows 10 technical preview, some sort of beta version, I'm assuming.

Just wanted to see if 10.1 will run ok on Windows 10 (ignoring the Mac aspect), as this is all I am using my windows interface for?

Comment: Microsoft puts a lot of work into making sure each version of Windows is backwards compatible with previous ones. I don't believe ArcGIS is "certified" to run on Win10, but it should work. Try it out, let us know.

Comment: It will run just not be supported (yet) until final product release.

Comment: It will *likely* run, but can't possibly be supported before final Microsoft release. It's possible that only 10.2.2 and 10.3 would be certified.

Comment: The answer to this question is yes, but I'm answering in a comment instead of an answer because the Windows 10 tech preview is no longer available.

Comment: I can confirm it works just fine on the 10240 build (as it did on prior builds), which is supposed to be "RTM".

Comment: @JasonScheirer. "Microsoft puts a lot of work into making sure each version of Windows is backwards compatible with previous ones". Discuss. I know that in the gaming world, this is true, that they used to deliberately mimic bugs from older versions that games had programmed into them. But, from a software dev perspective, this has not been my experience. If anything, I would say they deliberately break things to force people to upgrade. On the plus side, this means that C# is more powerful than Java, precisely because Sun were so careful to ensure everything was backwards compatible.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason on this one.  However, I do think it should remain closed because it is too broad to say that *everything* you want to do on a Windows version listed amongst the system requirements of ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop will also work on Windows 10 (let alone Windows 10 Technical Preview as in the question).

Comment: 1. [Official Win10 compatibility](http://support.esri.com/EM/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/45362). Glad the topic is now closed as opinion based now that we have a good non-opinion-based answer from the company itself.

Comment: 2. @JohnBarça that is an absolute non sequitur. The Microsoft operating systems group and the development tools group have different goals. OS: "Buy the new Windows? We'll still run your old programs!" Dev Tools: "Upgrade to new Visual Studio? SO MANY NEW FEATURES!!!!"

Answer (score 9):

I ran ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 on the Windows 10 Technical Preview for a couple months, over several different builds of Windows, and everything worked fine (I was on the "Fast" ring). I wasn't using it intensively but I didn't encounter any problems. However, I stopped using the Windows 10 Tech Preview around July 1 and went back to Windows 7, so I have *not* run ArcGIS on the latest version of the Tech Preview, which is supposedly the same build as the official Windows 10 that will roll out this week. I did have some compatibility problems with some software, but surprisingly, ArcGIS wasn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

This question, with the official release of Windows 10 is quickly turning into "this is my personal experience type of wiki".

Right now, today, the most current versions of [ArcGIS for Desktop](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/system-requirements/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm) (ArcMap 10.3.1 and [ArcGIS Pro 1.1](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/arcgis-pro-system-requirements.htm)), are **not** supported on Windows 10.

Historically Esri has introduced support for a new OS with the next release of a product AFTER the OS in question has officially released. That means work is underway for ArcMap-10.4 and ArcGIS Pro-1.2 (the next releases) to officially support Windows 10.
Of course older versions *may* (and probably will) work on the newer OS, but no official support mechanisms will exist if a problem does arise.

I'm actually voting to close this question as its clear to some degree it works. Unless theres a specific issue that comes up and can be asked as a specific question, further "yes, it works for me" answers aren't helpful.

Comment: The system requirements now mention: "** Windows 10 support begins at ArcGIS 10.3.1."

Answer (score 0):

I am running ArcGIS 10.3 on the official Windows 10 Pro through a VMWare VM on my mac, and have had no problems so far. I find it is running faster than it did in Windows 7 - although I may be imagining things.